# How to Get Teaser Images Or Images Of articles of zoo Joomla component

Tags: php, joomla

I am working on a Joomla System Plugin in which I need to fetch teaser image of an article of Zoo Joomla component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a work around: the getZooArticleTeaserImg function returns the image path

```
function getZooArticleTeaserImg($articleId){
    require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_zoo/config.php');
    $zapp     = App::getInstance('zoo');
    $zooitems = $zapp->table->item->all(array('conditions' => 'id = '.$articleId));
    $imgpath  = '';

    foreach($zooitems as $zooitem){
        foreach ($zooitem->getElements() as $zooid => $element){
            if(in_array($element->getElementType(), array('image', 'media'))){
                if($element->config->get('name') == 'Teaser Image'){
                    $imgpath = $element->get('file');
                }
                else if(!$imgpath && $element->config->get('name') == 'Image'){
                    $imgpath = $element->get('file');
                }  
           }
       }
    }

    return $imgpath;
}
```